# Angular 4 sort using orderby pipe not working

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

I am working on sorting column. but when I pass sort variable from component at that it is not working. 
working scenario :

```
<th>Contact</th>
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of (itemsToShow | orderBy:['-age', 'firstName'])">
</ng-container>
```

But when I try to set sort variable from component the same way in below code it is not working.
component file function :

```
changeOrderBy() {
 this.orderset = '['-age', 'firstName']';
}
```

HTML file:

```
<th (click)="changeOrderBy()">Contact</th>
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of (itemsToShow | orderBy:orderset )">
</ng-container>
```

Please see below link for reference:

http://embed.plnkr.co/DHLVc0

Comment: This looks like a code with a bug somewhere. I suggest taking a look at good practices to reduce your code complexity and improve quality. That will make the bug rather obvious. This is not an Angular issue.

Comment: By "This looks like a code with a bug somewhere", I meant: This looks like a complex code with a simple bug somewhere.

Comment: @AdrienBrunelat, I am not able to share all code. you can see reference link which I have mentioned in question

Comment: Yeah I checked the plunker, I was talking about that code. You need to reduce the Pipe's code complexity by refactoring. I'm pretty sure the error lies somewhere in that code. If that's still not enough, you can test this code with unit tests.

Comment: What I'm trying to make you realize is that your problem is not this particular bug, the problem is that your code quality is too low and that makes bug really hard to spot and fix.

Comment: @AdrienBrunelat. Are you are talking about orderBy.ts file from reference link?

Comment: yes I am talking about orderBy.ts. Code units are too large, it's full of `?` `:` and overall pretty hard to read.

Comment: @AdrienBrunelat. Sorry I also used this library from other place.

Comment: Oooh I didn't see the working scenario, my bad! But I think I have an answer for you.

Comment: @AdrienBrunelat.I am positive

Comment: Anything new on this?

Comment: Does angular 4 supports orderBy filter by default?

Answer (score 0):

I remember I used this pipe example, and had to change it because of some errors i got.

Here is how it looks now :

```
/*
 * Example use
 *      Basic Array of single type: *ngFor="let todo of todoService.todos | orderBy : '-'"
 *      Multidimensional Array Sort on single column: *ngFor="let todo of todoService.todos | orderBy : ['-status']"
 *      Multidimensional Array Sort on multiple columns: *ngFor="let todo of todoService.todos | orderBy : ['status', '-title']"
 */

import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'orderBy', pure: false })
export class OrderBy implements PipeTransform {

    value: string[] = [];

    static _orderByComparator(a: any, b: any): number {

        if (a === null || typeof a === 'undefined') { a = 0; };
        if (b === null || typeof b === 'undefined') { b = 0; };

        if (typeof a === 'string') { a = a.toLowerCase(); }
        if (typeof b === 'string') { b = b.toLowerCase(); }

        if ((isNaN(parseFloat(a)) || !isFinite(a)) || (isNaN(parseFloat(b)) || !isFinite(b))) {
            // Isn't a number so lowercase the string to properly compare
            if (a + ''.toLowerCase() < b + ''.toLowerCase()) { return -1; }
            if (a + ''.toLowerCase() > b + ''.toLowerCase()) { return 1; }
        } else {
            // Parse strings as numbers to compare properly
            if (parseFloat(a) < parseFloat(b)) { return -1; }
            if (parseFloat(a) > parseFloat(b)) { return 1; }
        }

        return 0; // equal each other
    }

    transform(input: any, config: string = '+'): any {

        // make a copy of the input's reference
        this.value = [...input];
        let value = this.value;

        if (!Array.isArray(value)) { return value; }

        if (!Array.isArray(config) || (Array.isArray(config) && config.length === 1)) {
            let propertyToCheck: string = !Array.isArray(config) ? config : config[0];
            let desc = propertyToCheck.toString().substr(0, 1) === '-';

            // Basic array
            if (!propertyToCheck || propertyToCheck === '-' || propertyToCheck === '+') {
                return !desc ? value.sort() : value.sort().reverse();
            } else {
                let property: string = propertyToCheck.toString().substr(0, 1) === '+' || propertyToCheck.toString().substr(0, 1) === '-'
                    ? propertyToCheck.toString().substr(1)
                    : propertyToCheck;

                return value.sort(function (a: any, b: any) {
                    return !desc
                        ? OrderBy._orderByComparator(a[property], b[property])
                        : -OrderBy._orderByComparator(a[property], b[property]);
                });
            }
        } else {
            // Loop over property of the array in order and sort
            return value.sort(function (a: any, b: any) {
                for (let i: number = 0; i < config.length; i++) {
                    let desc = config[i].substr(0, 1) === '-';
                    let property = config[i].substr(0, 1) === '+' || config[i].substr(0, 1) === '-'
                        ? config[i].substr(1)
                        : config[i];

                    let comparison = !desc
                        ? OrderBy._orderByComparator(a[property], b[property])
                        : -OrderBy._orderByComparator(a[property], b[property]);

                    // Don't return 0 yet in case of needing to sort by next property
                    if (comparison !== 0) { return comparison; }
                }

                return 0; // equal each other
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if I pass in this way "this.orderset = '['-age', 'firstName']';". will it work?

Comment: I can't tell you, you should create a StackBlitz example so we could help more. And what is orderbyset in orderBy:orderbyset ?  It shouldn't be orderset ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure changing pipe's arguments calls for a re-evaluation of said pipe's result.

Did you try to use a function inside your component instead? You could have the array of values as a property of your component and methods inside the component that sort the array according to your criteria.

```js
@Component( ... )
export class YourComponent {
  itemsToShow: Contact[];

  changeOrderBy() {
    SortUtils.sortArrayBy(this.itemsToShow, ['-age', 'firstName']);
  }
}

export class SortUtils {
  static sortArrayBy(array: any[], args: string[]) {
    // Your sort logic here...
    // You may copy/paste the code from the library
    // But I recommend rewrite the logic entirely instead.
  }
}
```